# Git commit uses fundamental mode after magit update

Tags: magit, major-mode, git

I recently updated `magit` to 20151025.1115, which gave me a message about `git-commit-mode` incompatibility.  I now, instead, have a package `git-commit` at version 20151022.933 (from the magit project) installed alongside `magit`, both through the `M-x list-packages` interface).  In my global git config, `core.editor=emacs -nw`.  My emacs is  version 24.5, compiled from source (Gentoo linux).

Before this update when I ran `git commit` from a terminal (outside of emacs), I would get an emacs instance in a mode aware of git commits -- "syntax" highlighting and `C-c C-c` to commit.

After this update when I run `git commit`, the emacs window is in Fundamental mode.  I can still commit with `C-s C-x` but the mode is not git aware and I lose helpful text coloring of my commit message.

**What do I need to change to get my terminal-launched commits to use a git-aware mode for commiting?**   Commiting within magit works as expected, I am just trying to "fix" the behavior from a git-launched `emacs -nw` session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the code which makes this happen has not been
loaded yet.  Maybe that code should be autoloaded, but currently it is
not.  (Unfortunately one can be fairly sure that if I did start to
autoload the relevant code, that then someone complains about that.)

This is the code which causes `git-commit-mode` to be used in buffers
visiting commit message buffers:

```
(add-to-list 'with-editor-server-window-alist
             (cons git-commit-filename-regexp 'switch-to-buffer))
```

So all you have to do is to add this to your init file:

```
(package-initialize) ; otherwise Emacs doesn't know were to find it
(setq package-initialize-at-startup nil) ; don't do it again

(global-git-commit-mode)
```

Additionally you might want to consider using `core.editor=emacsclient`.

Comment: Fwiw, the (require 'git-commit) did work.

Answer (score -1):

This builds a bit from what @tarsius mentioned above but is less convoluted. `git-commit-setup` hasn't been loaded yet.

I wonder if it has to do with changes in the latest update to `magit`, but you *have to* (??) manually load it.

You could do all that @tarsius mentioned or just add

`(global-git-commit-mode t)` to your startup

Comment: You cannot enable `global-git-commit-mode` if Emacs doesn't know where it is defined. That's why I provided a "convolved" explanation, which also explains how to tell Emacs about the package/library (by calling `package-initialize`).

Comment: You also should not call a minor-mode with `t` as argument. To turn on the mode no argument is required. In older Emacsen the argument was required, and one usually used `1` (one), not `t`. `t` appears to work as you intend for this particular mode, but there most certainly are modes which would fail with that argument.